# UIGestureRecognizer event between UIAlertView pop-up

Tags: iphone, ios, uialertview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a really weird issue, and it might be hard to explain, but I appreciate any help or suggestions on it.

I have a base view (View B) that has a UIGestureRecognizer that detects left and right gestures.

On top of View B, I have several small views (View C) that are covering the entire view.  (Think of it as a calendar).

On each View C I have a tap gesture recognizer, and a long press gesture recognizer.  On the tap gesture I display a UIAlertView.

So here's the problem:

I can tap View C and then swipe View B, and the View B swipe event fires before the UIAlertView displays.  This crashes my app, because when View B is removed with the swipe event and since View C is on top of View B they are removed as well, and the alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex: is not reached at all.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to prevent the swipe from happening before the UIAlertView displays? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try making a global `BOOL` variable in the .h file that says if the tap event is registered or not. In the method you call when a tap is registered, set the variable to `NO`, and in your method you call when a swipe is registered, check to see if the `BOOL` variable is `YES` or `NO`, and if it's `NO`, that means a tap has been registered, and you should not proceed with the swipe method. Then, simply set the `BOOL` variable to `YES` after the `UIAlertView` has been resigned. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

As you said, C Views entirely cover View B. Therefore, the swipe gestures on B should not be registered unless the alert has been displayed. You can add B's gesture recognizer in  `(void)didPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView;`.

And then in `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:`, you can remove B's gesture recognizer.

HTH,

Akshay